# RuntimeError: Only Tensors created explicitly by the user (graph leaves) support the deepcopy protocol at the moment

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor, deep-copy

Here is the error about deepcopy, how should I do it.
error:
target_encoder = copy.deepcopy(self.online_encoder)

RuntimeError: Only Tensors created explicitly by the user (graph leaves) support the deepcopy protocol at the moment

```html
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
            self,
            model, # byol
            projection_size=256,
            pred_size = 256,
            projection_hidden_size=4096,
            moving_average_decay=0.99,
            use_momentum=True,
    ):
        super(SSL, self).__init__()

        self.online_encoder = Pre_model(model) # 256

        self.use_momentum = use_momentum
        self.target_encoder = None
        self.target_ema_updater = EMA(moving_average_decay)


    def _get_target_encoder(self):
        target_encoder = copy.deepcopy(self.online_encoder)
        set_requires_grad(target_encoder, False)
        return target_encoder


    def forward(self, x):
        anchors = x['anchor'].cuda(non_blocking = True)
        neighbors = x['neighbor'].cuda(non_blocking = True)

        online_anchor_proj = self.online_encoder(anchors) 
        online_neighbor_proj = self.online_encoder(neighbors)


        with torch.no_grad():
            target_online = self._get_target_encoder() if self.use_momentum else self.online_encoder
            target_anchor_proj= target_online(anchors)
            target_neighbor_proj = target_online(neighbors)
```